# Question about continuity of a function to prove that it is Borel-measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, continuity

If $F(x,y)$ is a continuous function and I define $G(x)=\sup\{F(x,y) : y \in \mathbb{R} \}$. Will this function be continuous?

It would be really helpful because I'm trying to prove that $G$ is Borel- measurable.

Comment: If $F:X \times Y \to \mathbb{R}$, what are $X$ and $Y$? Are they both $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $F(x,y)=0$ if  $x<0$ or $y <0$, $\frac x y$ if $0\leq y<x$ and $1$ if $y \geq x$ then $F$ is continuous and $G(x)=0$ for $x <0$ and $G(x)=1$ for $x \geq 0$. Hence $G$ need not be continuous. However $G$ is measurable. We can write $\{x:G(x)<a\}=\cup_{y\in \mathbb q} \{x:F(x,y) <a\}$ which is a Borel set.

Comment: Alright that makes sense , just one question what is that $t$ refer to ??

Comment: That was  a typo. $t$ was supposed to be $a$.

Comment: Ah yes now it makes sense , thank you!